# R doesn't work properly with conda installation

Tags: r, conda

I tried installing r with conda and every time I try that it doesn't work.

```
conda create --name test2 -c conda-forge r-base r-seurat
```

I assumed that by using conda-forge channel, it will install the most updated version. What happened is that it installs the oldest version of R which is 3.6.1
At the same time, the "Seurat" package requires a newer version of R than 3.6.1
So, I specified a version of R in that code and it didn't work too

```
conda create --name test2 -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.1
```

This worked for installing a newer R version but when I try activating R on that environment, it gives me an error

> Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’

So, I opened rstudio from that environment and tried installing (beepr) package and it didn't work! It tries to install other packages as a requirement for it and at the same time gives the same error of not having "beepr" installed.
That's one of the packages it tried to install.

> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘glue’ had non-zero exit status Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’ Execution halted

and it does that with the rest of packages required.

That's the error I get from installing beepr

> also installing the dependencies ‘glue’, ‘magrittr’, ‘stringi’, ‘stringr’, ‘audio’ trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/glue_1.4.2.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 99049 bytes (96 KB) ================================================== downloaded 96 KB trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/magrittr_2.0.1.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 265580 bytes (259 KB) ================================================== downloaded 259 KB trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stringi_1.7.4.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7599762 bytes (7.2 MB) ================================================== downloaded 7.2 MB trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stringr_1.4.0.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 135777 bytes (132 KB) ================================================== downloaded 132 KB trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/audio_0.1-8.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 57390 bytes (56 KB) ================================================== downloaded 56 KB trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/beepr_1.3.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 922244 bytes (900 KB) ================================================== downloaded 900 KB Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’ Execution halted Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘glue’ had non-zero exit status Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’ Execution halted Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘magrittr’ had non-zero exit status Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’ Execution halted Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’ Execution halted Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘audio’ had non-zero exit status Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’ Execution halted Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status Error in library(beepr) : there is no package called ‘beepr’ Execution halted Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘beepr’ had non-zero exit status The downloaded source packages are in ‘/tmp/Rtmp0CeBTl/downloaded_packages’ Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library' Making 'packages.html' ... done Warning in install.packages : converting NULL pointer to R NULL Warning message: R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.

Did anyone face that issue before?

Comment: What platform? For example, on **osx-64** the first command works fine for me. However, including `r-beepr` forces things down to R v3.6.1 because only an old version of that and `r-audio` are available on Anaconda Cloud. Unfortunately, using `install.packages` for compiled (from source) does not work out-of-the-box with Conda R environments.

Comment: BTW, I put in a couple PRs to add [`r-audio`](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/16225) and [`r-beepr`](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/16226) to Conda Forge. I'll ping again once they're merged.

Comment: Those packages are now built by Conda Forge, including R 4.0 and 4.1 versions. You should now not be limited to R 3.6 and installing everything through Conda should avoid these issues.